# C# object modification

Tags: c#, constructor, pass-by-reference

*I think this is really a very lame question, but I guess on `SO` I will receive the answer faster than by googling it myself :)*

Let's say I have some class with a constructor:

```
public class TestClass {

   private readonly IRepository repository;

   public TestClass(IRepository repository)
   {
      this.repository = repository;

      // Here is the non-obvious line - it invokes some
      // method, which changes the internal contents of
      // the repository object.
      repository.AddSomething(...);
   }
}
```

*And now:*

```
IRepository sqlRepository = new SqlRepository(...);

TestClass testClass = new TestClass(sqlRepository);
```

---

**1)** I'm not good at value / reference passing in `C#` - so please could someone give a **step-by-step** explanation of what happens in this case.

**2)** Does the `sqlRepository` object get modified *(I assume not)* and is there a way to make the constructor of `TestClass` **modify it** (I know it's evil, just for me to know)?

**3)** Would the `repository.AddSomething(...)` and `this.repository.AddSomething(...)` lines in the constructor have the same effect and why?

**4)** What effect does `readonly` have on the attempts of the repository changes in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In this case the reference to `sqlRespository` is passed into the ctor.
2. Not yet. When you call `AddSomething()`, that method is indeed modifying the original instance. We still only have one object and everyone is touching that one. It's an important distinction that since everyone has a reference to the same object, any changes they make will be made *to that object*. However, if they simply overwrite that variable with a different object, that only applies locally. Remember, variables are like slots. We can have lots of slots that all point back to the same object, but replacing one slot with a pointer to a *different* object doesn't affect the other slots.
3. *If* you first set `this.repository = repository` then both the local parameter called `repository` and member variable (field) called `repository` hold a reference to the same object. We use `this.` to be clear we mean the member variable (field) and *not* the local parameter or variable.
4. `readonly` means that member variable / field can only be assigned from the constructor. Think of the member variable as a slot where we can put an object. If the slot is `readonly`, that means it can only be filled during the ctor call. After that it can't be replaced. That does *not* mean that the object inside of it is somehow "read-only". The object can still be modified, it just can't be replaced by another object.